# Embedded Flash <object>: extra resource, force a particular URL

Tags: flash, model-view-controller

Is it possible to specify the Domain for extra resource for the flash object?

I have a page with `<OBJECT>` tag and a flash obj.

The issue is that the flash app try to access to some extra resource (images, mp3, etc.) and because it is Embedded in ad index.php with MVC model it is pointing to the wrong URL.

**Details:**

1. swf is hosted in `BASE_URL/media/`
2. swf point to -> `BASE_URL/index.php/files/...`
3. Files are hosted in `BASE_URL/media/files/`

Any way to force the flash to point to a particular dir. without changing the .swf code and so directly in the `<OBJECT>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It is possible to fix this using `base` attribute of the `<OBJECT>` tag

reference:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html